How quietly can a flute manage this high note?
As far as I can tell from this wiki page, this note (B#6) is still playable on a flute, though it’s not easy:

But how quietly can it be played? Can it be done in pp or p dynamics?

In some practices, dynamics are not absolute, and also pp doesn’t mean “very quiet”, it means “very soft”. What I’m suggesting is that this question would be easier to answer if it were more about how this note marked p or pp would sound compared with another instrument at the same time playing a certain note with a certain mark.

Piccolo might be a better option.

That note on a flute is going to be piercing, no matter how many decibels it measures. Here's a piccolo playing in that range. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EFLa5dK-nU

@Lii It is possible to play that note in a softer colour, without it sounding too piercing. It also goes higher than the notes in the video you linked. Piccolo has a very different timbre than flute as well.

At the other end of the scale, the Taktakishvili flute sonata ends with four middle C's, fortissimo. The flute just can't play its lowest note loud enough to be heard over the piano.

@MarkLutton - Do you mean the second movement: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAe0lbjvW4A ?

@brilliant Third movement. https://youtu.be/8ifWRRbEsZ8?si=U8YWZd-p1Hx1Ea9L When Cassie White and I performed it and made this recording, she played the four notes an octave up. But the flutist in your link left them out entirely.

@MarkLutton - That's your own recording?! Very impressive! The quality of sound and overall delivery is more than commendable! "But the flutist in your link left them out entirely" - To me it's almost like a crime against the author.

@brilliant - I looked up the sheet music online and found an edition that leaves the last four flute notes out. That is probably the edition your flutist used, but our edition has the four notes. Re the recording, we made it at Studio Metronome in my town; I know the owner and he gave me a good price and had his best recording engineer on it, an engineer who already had a Grammy, an Oscar, two or three gold records and one platinum.

It's certainly well within the realm of possibility, although it requires a certain level of playing, as PiedPiper alludes to. For example, the Ligeti Violin Concerto has this exact note (though spelled as a C7) in the fourth movement for flute 1, marked sempre p possibile. There are a myriad of alternate fingerings flutists can try to make the note more stable at a very quiet dynamic.

"...for example, the Ligeti Violin Concerto has this exact note" - I just found it on YouTube. Yes, exactly that note and amazingly quet! Thank you!

It depends on the player and to some extent on context. A professional orchestral player will have no problem playing that high B-sharp as quietly as you want.
Don't write it in a part for a high school band.

I feel like you're underestimating high school band flautists a little :). It's not that difficult to play this note relatively softly (some of the barriers are psychological, though, and some of them are tuning!). But more seriously, this particular note is the highest "commonly taught" note on the flute. If you go higher than that, the flute section will all be reaching for specialist fingering charts and flubbing their notes because they don't have the muscle memory for those notes. Same if you add a trill. And...sort of the same with that key signature, too!
